# ansible variable scope not broad enough

Tags: scope, ansible

I have a role called get_install_command that runs a local python script which returns a command that needs to be run on a remote server. The role get_install_command sets a variable called "install_command" which the role "install" attempts to use. Here is my code:

```
 - hosts: localhost
   roles:
     - get_install_command

 - hosts: remote_host
   roles:
     - install
```

however I get this error:

```
"installation_command.stdout_lines": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
```

What should I do to fix this? It seems to me that I need to put this variable in a higher scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables defined in a play using `register` or `set_fact` are scoped **to the host on which the task is running**.  So since you run `get_install_command` on `localhost`, the `install_command` variable is available on `localhost`.

The documentation covers [how to access variables defined on another host](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#accessing-information-about-other-hosts-with-magic-variables).  You want something like this:

```
hostvars.localhost.install_command.stdout
```